# Java Program Error - String Input Not Available

Tags: java, string, input, runtime-error

This is my code:

```
package Class;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bicycle 
{    
    public static int units;
    public static int courseNum;
    public static String courseName;

    public Bicycle(int startUnits, int startNum, String startName) 
    {
        units = startUnits;
        courseNum = startNum;
        courseName = startName;
    }

    public static int setUnits(int newValue) 
    {
        units = newValue;
        return units;
    }

    public static int setNum(int newValue)
    {
        courseNum = newValue;
        return courseNum;
    }

    public static String setName(String newValue) 
    {
        courseName = newValue;
        return courseName;
    }

    public class subClass extends Bicycle 
    {
        public int randVariable;

        public subClass(int startUnits, int startNum, String startName) 
        {
            super(startUnits, startNum, startName);
        }   

        public void randVariable(int newValue) 
        {
            randVariable = newValue;
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        int BaseUnits;
        int BaseCourseNum;
        String BaseCourseName;

        int FinalUnits;
        int FinalCourseNum;
        String FinalCourseName;

        Scanner entries = new Scanner(System.in);

        BaseUnits = entries.nextInt();
        BaseCourseNum = entries.nextInt();
        BaseCourseName = entries.nextLine();

        FinalUnits = setUnits(BaseUnits);
        FinalCourseNum = setNum(BaseCourseNum);
        FinalCourseName = setName(BaseCourseName);

        System.out.printf("The Course ");
        System.out.println(FinalCourseName);
        System.out.printf(" (CIS %d) is worth %d units.", FinalCourseNum, FinalUnits);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get a string input, and although I am using the code that would do that, the program never actually asks me to enter that string.

Comment: _the program never ask you to enter_, but probably it waiting for you to enter

Comment: Instance fields *should not* be static! Also, don't name your package `Class`.

Comment: Possibly your issue: [Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

Comment: Yeah you really need to make an instance of `Bicycle` and not use static methods as @ElliottFrisch said

Comment: @Jonjongot It isn't waiting either. It just skips it and moves on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner entries = new Scanner(System.in);

        BaseUnits = entries.nextInt();
        BaseCourseNum = entries.nextInt();
        BaseCourseName = entries.next(); //<--
```

use next() instead of nextLine();
read this [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) for further clearification.

Answer (score 0):

your code snippets is taking input from user at below line

Scanner entries = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    BaseCourseName = entries.nextLine();
```

either you can change this to

```
    BaseCourseName = entries.nextLine();
```

or

you can take input from  BufferedReader also as given below.

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

```
    String line = br.readLine();
```